# Add a txt file to the root of the host server from a Docker container

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose

I am running a python file from a Docker container. I want to add a txt file with some data from the python file to a newly created txt file at the root of the host server, and I have to do this several times. Is there any way to do this from the python file?

Comment: host server means ? outside of docker container ?

Comment: Have you used volumes before? Mount the destination directory on the host to a directory on the container that the files are written to

Comment: And BTW: you don't put data into the root of the file system!

Comment: @Abhishek yes outside of the docker container.

Comment: @KlausD. I want to communicate with different files on the system so I needed to put a reserve file on the root

Comment: @IainShelvington I'll try that, thanks

Comment: as Iain suggested use volume mount the destination dir in which you want to add  the file as a target and then write the file there, it will get  saved inside your host server dir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [docker volumes](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/). You can write to the file from inside the container at `<mount path in container>` and access it from host at `<path on host>`

```
docker run -v <path on host>:<mount path in container> <image>
```